# Как получить значение переменной из другого класса java

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу разобраться как можно получить значение переменной.

Есть 2 класса, получается в классе с главным методом я задаю параметры и элементы фрейма. Я так понимаю, что мне нужно будет там получить значения, чтобы в дальнейшем их все записать в текстовый документ.

Во втором классе я создаю панель, на которой располагаются кнопки. Для каждой кнопки я таким образом добавила счетчик

```
Exellent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    int E;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        E++;
        System.out.println("E="+E); /*просто вывод, чтоб проследить за работой*/
    }
});
```

В итоге мне нужно получить с каждой кнопки эти значения `E` и прочие, но вне слушателя к ним обратиться не могу...

Comment: возможно я вообще не о том спрашиваю, может мне и не нужно получать эти значения в главном классе, но из слушателя его как-то надо достать...

Comment: в классах поля обычно [инкапсулируют](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). После инкапсуляции для объекта класса значение можно получить через функцию `get` (в данном случае -- `getE`). Также, я бы вынес код инкрементации E и печати нового значения в отдельную функцию `incE()`.

Answer (score 0):

Кнопка, на которой было событие добавляется в `ActionEvent`. Поэтому вы можете получить значения, если обратиться к родительскому компоненту, а также если компоненты доступны за пределами класса.

```
((JButton)e.getSource()).getParent()
```

В противном случае придется создавать анонимный класс слушателя событий внутри родительского компонента

```
private JLabel label;
private JButton button;

Panel() {
    ...
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      int E;

      @Override  
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setText("кнопка была нажата");
        E++;
        System.out.println("E="+E); /*просто вывод, чтоб проследить за работой*/
      }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Обратиться вы к ним не можете, потому что создаете *анонимный класс* (`new ActionListener() {...}`). Создайте новый класс, который реализует ActionListener.

Примерно так:

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener { 
    int E;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        E++;
        System.out.println("E="+E); /*просто вывод, чтоб проследить за работой*/
    }
}
```

Затем создайте ссылку на слушатель (`ActionListener btnListener = new ButtonListener()`), и добавляйте этот слушатель к кнопке:

```
Exellent.addActionListener(btnListener);
```

А потом просто получайте значение из `btnListener`.